# How to export and import multiple functions inside component? vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

In my **Date.js**, I'm trying to export multiple functions, but it fails and returned an bunch of errors.

```
import moment from 'moment';

let today = moment();

const age = function(date) { return today.diff(moment(date), 'years'); }
const ageGreaterThan = function(date, age) { return age(date) > age; }
//more functions here

export default age, ageGreaterThan;
```

In my **Signup.vue**, I'm trying to import the file above, as it expected it fails.

```
import Datex from './../util/Date.js';

export default{
    data(){ datex: new Datex },

    methods: {
        sample(val){ return this.datex.age(val); }
    }
}
```

I'm really confuse to this [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export), someone can help me how to do this?

Comment: `Datex` isn't a class, however you can do: `import * as Datex from './../util/Date.js'` and to use `Datex.age()`

Comment: did u read this blog? 
https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/multi-export-vue-single-file-ui-components/
I think it will be helpful for u

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you could export the const directly like this:

#### Option 1 - use direct export `export const func`

```js
import moment from 'moment';

let today = moment();

export const age = function(date) { return today.diff(moment(date), 'years'); }
export const ageGreaterThan = function(date, ageVal) { return this.age(date) > ageVal; }
//more functions here
```

note that since you're not using `defaults` object, the import will need to use `* as` form

```js
import * as Datex from '../util/Date.js
```

#### Option 2 - create functions and wrap for export in defaults object

```js
import moment from 'moment';

let today = moment();

const age = function(date) { return today.diff(moment(date), 'years'); }
const ageGreaterThan = function(date, ageVal) { return this.age(date) > ageVal; }
//more functions here

export default {
   age,
   ageGreaterThan,
   // the other functions
}
```

#### Option 3 - define functions in the export object directly

```js
import moment from 'moment';
let today = moment();

export default {
   age(date) {
      return today.diff(moment(date), 'years')
   },
   ageGreaterThan(date, ageVal) {
      return this.age(date) > ageVal;
   },
   // the other functions
}
```

---

The problem, in the component is that you're treating it as a Class as opposed to an object. You should remove `new Datex()` and use `Datex.*()` directly (where * is the function)

If you're using Option 2 or 3 from above, you can then import this way. (For Option 1, see not above re. using `* as`)
In your component, you then do...

```js
import Datex from '../util/Date.js';

export default{

    methods: {
        sample(val){ return Datex.age(val); }
    }
}
```

or you can import only the functions you need directly

```js
import { age, ageGreaterThan } from "../util/Date.js";

export default{

    methods: {
        sample(val){ return age(val); }
    }
}
```

Comment: still receiving this error **TypeError: _util_Moment_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.default is not a constructor** Sir

Comment: *"export 'age' was not found in './../util/Date.js'*

Comment: looks like you're using 1st example. I should have specified that you need to import this way, since default is not used `import * as Datex from '../util/Date.js'`

Comment: when I call the **ageGreaterThan()** an error returned *"TypeError: age is not a function"*

Comment: you need to be explicit which `age` you are using. if you're passing `age` as a parameter of the function, use `age()`. If you're relying on the age function defined in same file, you should use `this.age()`

Comment: I tried `this.age()` but this errors shows, *Error in render: "TypeError: output is undefined"*

Comment: `output is undefined` seems like that could be a problem with the age function itself

Comment: I tried to console.log the `this.age(date)` inside the **ageGreaterThan()** it returns **NaN**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210613/discussion-between-daniel-and-charles).

Answer (score 0):

a fast example:

```
// use/loading.js

import { Loading } from "quasar";
import { i18n } from "../../app/src/boot/i18n";

export default {
  show: (message = null) => {
    Loading.show({
      message: `${i18n.t(message || "request_processing")} ...`
    });
  },

  hide: () => Loading.hide()
};
```

to use in component

```
import loading from "use/loading";

export default {
  ...
  methods: {
    async myFunction() {
      loading.show();

      try {
        await fetchAPI()
      } catch (e) {
        // HANDLE ERROR
      }
      loading.hide();
    }
  },
  ...
};
</script>
```

Comment: I tried this method but returns me an error *Error in render: "TypeError: can't convert undefined to object"*